# Virtual memory allowed space for OBIEE 11g

Tags: oracle11g

i'm going to install obiee 11g in windows 7, but failed because swap space memory is 0, then
i go to my computer, to see my virtual memory setting, but i confuse to fill the number in custom size,
Custom size:
Initial size(mb):
maximum size(mb):
how should i fill the number?so when i install obiee 11g there is no problem about virtual memory anymore

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

OBIEE 11g requires 8gb ram to run.
You should definetly check the technical requirements before trying to install.
Documentation and install instructions are on www.oracle.com

Also be aware that there are some common issues people face that are not covered in the documentation and where documentation is wrong!- this happens is more likely if you are installing 64bit rather than 32 bit.

A google of this will show you these.

Hope this helps.